# TIdTCPServer OnExecute not fired for some messages unless mouse in window

Tags: c++builder, indy10

We have a Windows app that we're adding a socket interface for remote configuration and data processing.  A TIdTCPServer object receives the messages in the OnExecute event.  For some messages, however, the OnExecute event is not fired unless the cursor is moved in the main window.

UPDATE: With a lot more experimenting, whether or not the message is processed immediately, or after a long pause, or not at all, seems more random.  In all cases, moving the cursor causes the message to be processed immediately.  However, it doesn't seem to be specific to a message, or the order of messages.

Updated source code listings:  Here's the OnExecute handler:

```
void __fastcall TSigToolForm::IdTCPServer1Execute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    TIdBytes buffer;
    if (ReceiveBuffer(AContext, buffer))
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                msg = &buffer[0];                   // msg is class member
                TThread::Synchronize(0, mProcess);  // Doesn't return until mProcess finishes
                buffer = IPOK().toByteArray();      // Ack
                SendBuffer(AContext, buffer);
            }
            catch (const std::exception & ex)
            {
                buffer = IPFailCommand(ex.what()).toByteArray();
                SendBuffer(AContext, buffer);
            }
            catch (const Exception & ex)
            {
                buffer = IPFailCommand(toStdString(ex.Message)).toByteArray();
                SendBuffer(AContext, buffer);
            }
            catch (const EIdException & ex)
            {
                throw;                              // Let Indy have it
            }
        }
        __finally
        {
            msg = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The mProcess function and the processMessage function it calls.  I stripped all but one message type that processMessage handles:

```
void __fastcall TSigToolForm::mProcess()
{
    if (msg) processMessage(msg);
}

void TSigToolForm::processMessage(byte * message)
{
    CSLock lock(cs);            // RAII class, cs is TCriticalSection
    try
    {
        IPCommand cmd(message);
        switch (cmd.ID)
        {
            case IPCommand::SET_CAD :
            {
                setObjectCad(cmd);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception & ex)
    {
        ShowMessage(ex.what());
    }
    catch (const EIdException & ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ShowMessage("Exception in processMessage");
    }
}
```

The ReceiveBuffer and SendBuffer functions:

```
bool ReceiveBuffer(TIdTCPClient * aClient, TIdBytes & ABuffer)
{
    return ReceiveBuffer(aClient->IOHandler, ABuffer);
}


bool ReceiveBuffer(TIdContext * AContext, TIdBytes & ABuffer)
{
    return ReceiveBuffer(AContext->Connection->IOHandler, ABuffer);
}


bool ReceiveBuffer(TIdIOHandler * IO, TIdBytes & ABuffer)
{
    CSLock lock(cs);
    try
    {
        long sz = IO->ReadLongInt();
        IO->ReadBytes(ABuffer, sz, false);
        return true;
    }
    catch (const EIdException & ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return false;
}


bool SendBuffer(TIdIOHandler * IO, const TIdBytes & ABuffer)
{
    CSLock lock(cs);
    try
    {
        IO->WriteBufferOpen();
        try
        {
            IO->Write(ABuffer.Length);
            IO->Write(ABuffer);
            IO->WriteBufferClose();
        }
        catch(const Exception &)
        {
            IO->WriteBufferCancel();
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch(const EIdException &)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


bool SendBuffer(TIdContext * AContext, const TIdBytes & ABuffer)
{
    return SendBuffer(AContext->Connection->IOHandler, ABuffer);
}

bool SendBuffer(TIdTCPClient * aClient, const TIdBytes & aBuffer)
{
    return SendBuffer(aClient->IOHandler, aBuffer);
}
```

For testing I have a separate program that creates and send the various messages, using TIdTCPClient and the same send / receive buffer functions.  This is the only connection to the server program.  Here's an example:

```
void TForm16::setPortAndConnect()
{
    IdTCPClient1->Port = bdePort->IntValue();
    IdTCPClient1->Host = editHost->Text;
    IdTCPClient1->Connect();
}

void TForm16::sendCommandToSVST(const TIdBytes & buffer)
{
    try
    {
        setPortAndConnect();
        if (SendBuffer(IdTCPClient1, buffer))
        {
            TIdBytes recv;
            //
            // Read the response
            if (ReceiveBuffer(IdTCPClient1, recv))
            {
                IPCommand response = IPCommand::fromByteArray(recv);
            }
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        IdTCPClient1->Disconnect();
    }
}
```

bdePort is an internal TEdit-derived that deals with numerical input.  I'm confident that the data itself is correct.  It's getting the server to respond that is a problem right now.

I assume at this point that there must be something the program itself is doing that's interfering with the GUI thread or the socket connection or both.  I know this is very open-ended, but any hints on what to look for would be appreciated.

This is C++Builder 10.1 update 1, using the classic compiler.

Answer (score 1):

> For some messages, however, the OnExecute event is not fired unless the cursor is moved in the main window.

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component, the `OnExecute` event is fired in a worker thread in a continuous loop for the lifetime of the socket connection.  So the ONLY way it could be getting blocked until mouse activity is detected is if your `OnExecute` code is synchronizing with the main UI thread, and the main UI thread is blocked until window messages are received.

In the code you have shown, the only places where your `OnExecute` code could be getting blocked are the calls to `ReceiveBuffer()`, `mProcess()`, and `SendBuffer()`.  Make sure they are all thread-safe.  You did not show the code for any of those methods, or the code for your main UI thread, but `mProcess()` is being called via  `TThread::Synchronize()` so start with that one and make sure your main UI thread is not blocking `mProcess()` while it is trying to process a socket message.

BTW, you are catching only STL-based exceptions (derived from `std::exception`), but you are completely ignoring RTL-based exceptions (derived from `System::Sysutils::Exception`).  And in the case of Indy-based exceptions (which are derived from `EIdException`, which itself is derived from `System::Sysutils::Exception`), DO NOT swallow them!  If you catch an Indy exception, re-throw it and let `TIdTCPServer` handle it, otherwise its threads will not be able to detect socket disconnects and clean up properly (unless you manually call `AContext->Connection->Disconnect()` in your code).

> Don't know the Indy version, whatever came with the compiler.

You can find out the Indy version by:

- looking for Indy in the IDE's "About" box
- right-clicking on any Indy component in the Form Designer at design-time.
- reading the `Version` property of any Indy component at runtime.

**UPDATE:** Why are you using a critical section around everything? You don't need that.

You are reading/writing a client socket from only 1 thread (the one firing the `OnExecute` event). Even if you were reading in one thread and writing in another thread, that is safe to do with sockets without placing a lock around the IOHandler. So you don't need a lock around those IOHandler operations at all.

And your `mProcess()` method is already being serialized by `TThread::Synchronize()`, so it will only ever run in the main UI thread. If multiple client threads want to call `mProcess()` at the same time, `Synchronize()` ensures it runs only one at a time. So you don't need a lock for that, either. However, your use of `ShowMessage()` inside of `mProcess()` is problematic, because it runs a secondary message loop that will allow pending `Synchronize()` requests to run while `mProcess()` is still running, so you can end up with multiple `mProcess()` calls overlapping each other. You should not be doing anything inside of a synced method that can cause window messages to be processed. If a synced method throws an exception, you should not try to catch it.  `Synchronize()` catches exceptions and rethrows them in the context of the thread that called `Synchronize()`, and you already have exception handlers in your `OnExecute` code.

The only place I see where you should be using any kind of lock, if any at all, would be inside of `setObjectCad()`, but only if it needs to access data that can be accessed by multiple threads at the same time.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```cpp
void ReceiveBuffer(TIdTCPClient * aClient, TIdBytes & ABuffer)
{
    ReceiveBuffer(aClient->IOHandler, ABuffer);
}

bool ReceiveBuffer(TIdContext * AContext, TIdBytes & ABuffer)
{
    ReceiveBuffer(AContext->Connection->IOHandler, ABuffer);
}

void ReceiveBuffer(TIdIOHandler * IO, TIdBytes & ABuffer)
{
    long sz = IO->ReadLongInt();
    IO->ReadBytes(ABuffer, sz, false);
}

void SendBuffer(TIdIOHandler * IO, const TIdBytes & ABuffer)
{
    IO->WriteBufferOpen();
    try
    {
        IO->Write(ABuffer.Length);
        IO->Write(ABuffer);
        IO->WriteBufferClose();
    }
    catch(const Exception &)
    {
        IO->WriteBufferCancel();
        throw;
    }
}

void SendBuffer(TIdContext * AContext, const TIdBytes & ABuffer)
{
    SendBuffer(AContext->Connection->IOHandler, ABuffer);
}

void SendBuffer(TIdTCPClient * aClient, const TIdBytes & aBuffer)
{
    SendBuffer(aClient->IOHandler, aBuffer);
}
```

```cpp
void __fastcall TSigToolForm::IdTCPServer1Execute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    TIdBytes buffer;
    ReceiveBuffer(AContext, buffer);

    try
    {
        msg = &buffer[0];                   // msg is class member
        TThread::Synchronize(0, mProcess);  // Doesn't return until mProcess finishes
        buffer = IPOK().toByteArray();      // Ack
        SendBuffer(AContext, buffer);
    }
    catch (const std::exception & ex)
    {
        buffer = IPFailCommand(ex.what()).toByteArray();
        SendBuffer(AContext, buffer);
    }
    catch (const Exception & ex)
    {
        buffer = IPFailCommand(toStdString(ex.Message)).toByteArray();
        SendBuffer(AContext, buffer);
        if (dynamic_cast<const EIdException *>(&ex))
            throw;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        buffer = IPFailCommand("Unknown exception").toByteArray();
        SendBuffer(AContext, buffer);
    }
}

void __fastcall TSigToolForm::mProcess()
{
    if (msg) processMessage(msg);
}

void TSigToolForm::processMessage(byte * message)
{
    IPCommand cmd(message);
    switch (cmd.ID)
    {
        case IPCommand::SET_CAD :
        {
            setObjectCad(cmd);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void TSigToolForm::setObjectCad(const IPCommand &cmd)
{
    // here is where you should be using CSLock, if at all...
}
```

```cpp
void TForm16::setPortAndConnect()
{
    IdTCPClient1->Port = bdePort->IntValue();
    IdTCPClient1->Host = editHost->Text;
    IdTCPClient1->Connect();
}

void TForm16::sendCommandToSVST(const TIdBytes & buffer)
{
    setPortAndConnect();
    try
    {
        // Send the command
        SendBuffer(IdTCPClient1, buffer);

        // Read the response
        TIdBytes recv;
        ReceiveBuffer(IdTCPClient1, recv);
        IPCommand response = IPCommand::fromByteArray(recv);
    }
    __finally
    {
        IdTCPClient1->Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Indy version is 10.6.2.5341

Comment: The current verson is 10.6.2.5499. You should consider upgrading your copy of Indy.

Comment: I'm willing.  Is there someplace to pick up the BPLs, etc.?

Comment: BPLs are compiler-specific. Indy does not provide pre-built BPLs for download. You have to compile Indy yourself using your particular compiler  [Instructions and download links](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) are on Indy's website.

Comment: @user2113260 I updated my answer based on your updated question. You are doing things in your code that you should not be doing

Comment: Implemented your suggested code changes but not affect on the behavior; still hangs until mouse motion in the form (or the taskbar icon).  Downloaded latest Indy version but it does not create any binary files.  Are these instructions still valid?  C++Builder Compiling

Indy does not include BPK project files for C++Builder, so you will need to use the FULLC#.BAT command-line script that corresponds to your version of C++Builder.  This will compile the DPK files using C++Builder's command-line Delphi compiler (dcc32.exe) or MSBuild toolchain (msbuild.exe), depending on IDE version.

Comment: @user2113260 yes, the install instructions are still valid. As for your issue, we can't see your project(s), so what EXACTLY are you doing in your main UI thread(s) while the server/client are running? Mouse actions and `Synchronize()` requests need a responsive message loop in the main UI thread. Is your main thread calling `sendCommandToSVST()`? That code blocks the main message loop from running until the socket is disconnected, unless you place a `TIdAntiFreeze` on your Form. DON'T perform blocking operations in the main thread. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue in action.